# Is it inefficient to run VS2012 and my SQL Server on the same machine?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, azure

I am developing a ASP.NET MVC4 application that runs on Azure. I use simple membership for authentication and my data is mostly stored in tablestorage. This includes the source for web pages which is stored in one row of table storage.

Recently I am having huge performance problems with pages in the local environment taking 10-60 seconds to appear. I have tried using the local web server and IIS Express but there's not much difference. Things still run slow.

One thing I recall is recently I switched to using Simple Membership and I now have the following connect string:

```
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebUx-20121229234926;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebUx-20121229234926.mdf" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I see a SQL Server process running in the task manager. Is it possible this could be very slow. My memory usage is 70% of 3GB. Any suggestions?  Do you think it would be better if I change to use the SQL Server I have running on the cloud.

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=xxx.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=selftestware;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xx;Password=yy" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I am open to try anything. Just want my pages to come up locally in less than a minute :-(

Comment: Which edition of SQL Server do you have installed? Consider using SQL Express if you don't need the full-whack Developer (rebranded Enterprise) edition.

Comment: I am using Windows 8 (stupid move on my part). I am not even sure how to check which version. I will go looking :-(  First I need to find the start button.

Comment: So are you saying performance used to NOT be a problem on a machine with only 3GB of ram?

Comment: @GregD: It shouldn't be - back in 2005 I had a fairly perfomant webserver that ran IIS6 and SQL Server 2000 on only 256MB of RAM... oh, and it ran Exchange 2003 too!

Comment: I run VS2012 with Resharper, IIS8 on Win8 with 8GB of ram and it's slow enough to bug me.

Comment: To be fair, ever since VS2010 I've found the whole user-experience to be very slow and sluggish. I run VS2012 on an SSD and 16GB machine at work - still no cure for menus that take 5 seconds to load.

Comment: Task manager is showing that I am using: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\LocalDB\Binn

Comment: I have a dev database in Azure and I hit that and the performance is actually better for me with that setup vs. using my local database, so why not try it?

Comment: @GregD RAM is not the be-all and end-all. Get an SSD, assuming you've got at least a Core 2.

Comment: @Dai Try disabling any plugins you have and seeing if performance is still slow. Otherwise get your hands on http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fa85b17d-3df2-49b1-bee6-71527ffef441

Comment: @GregD - How much better do you find it? When running locally what kind of setup do you have. Ram and speed. I am just wondering if I have hit the limit on my machine. I look at the disk access light. It flashes for a second and then nothing for another 5 seconds and this goes on for about a minute sometimes before the page appears.

Comment: @ta.speot.is I have a stock VS2012 installation.

Comment: @GredD - You mention your setup is slow. Did you notice any problems after moving to Windows 8 other than the lack of a start button.

Comment: Following up I used Web Installer and it shows I have Microsoft SQL Express Local DB edition installed.

Comment: @Marilou - Actually in my case, speed improved slightly on Windows 8.  I bought Start8 to get my start button back.

Answer (score 1):

The important thing is to profile your code. This can be as simple as wrapping database calls with calls to `Stopwatch`.

My guess is that your application is making numerous, chatty, calls to the Azure web service, over your residential Internet connection, which is probably going to be at least ~100ms, maybe even up to 2000ms if you're connecting through a Mobile Broadband (3G) service.

Azure applications run faster on MS' servers because they have a low-latency connection to their database servers, you do not have this luxury.

I suggest you configure your application to use only your local SQL Server.

Don't worry about initial page-requests - those will always be slow on ASP.NET as it recompiles your *.aspx/Razor files, it's all the subsequent requests that matter.

Comment: It is configured to use the local SQL Server, and local emulators now :-(  Yes initial page requests are slower. 60 seconds approx vs 20-30 for subsequent.

Comment: Then that makes profiling easier. Profile!